# Border without margin to picture

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

If I border a img the border has a margin and the img gets a white padding.
How can I take the margin off the border?

I have it like this: `border: 1px solid gray;`

Answer (score 0):

Tipically you shuold set to zero the margin and the padding for the some element 
try this way

```
body, div, img {  
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```